# Data export import failed to import into Drupal 7

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I using "[Data Export Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import)" module to export all articles from site Drupal 6 and import it to site Drupal 7.

I export all taxonomy terms in site Drupal 6 and import the dataset into site Drupal 7.

The error messages:

> There is a mismatch between the vocabularies in the dataset file and
>   the current vocabularies - vocabulary name: News The Taxonomy Terms
>   dataset file 20150824_113732_taxonomy_terms.dataset was not imported.

How should I correct the error?

Comment: Do you have an existing vocabulary called "News" on your D7 site?

Comment: @AlexLaughnan Yes, It already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you can't since this module wasn't created for 6-7 migration. (It's too bad, too.)

From the *Data Export Import* project page:

> NB - This module has primarily been developed to move data between the same versions of Drupal - to move data between a live site and a development/beta site.
>
> It may be possible that the taxonomy terms and users data files exported from Drupal 6 can be imported into a Drupal 7 site (or the other way around). This has not been tested yet and any feedback would be gratefully received.

You could try contacting the maintainer through the issue queue, see if it's a small thing they can fix, but since the project is currently looking for a new maintainer I wouldn't expect a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

On D7, This issue can be fixed up by matching vocabulary(id) on both sites. Just create only vocabularies(not terms) with same vid and machinename as live site has.

Thanks!